# Issue with foreach + get-childitem

Tags: powershell

I'm doing a script to organize my media. I download files in one directory to accomodate them before adding to my media center.
If for example I have a file called `Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi` I would like the script to get the name of the show, check for season on S01 and move that file to a folder in another disk, for example `e:\series\breaking bad\season 01`
So far it checks if the file is call s01e01 or S01E01 or s01.e01 or S01.E01 and returns Breaking Bad\Season 01, creates the path to move to and the moving action itself

I have part of that script but I cannot make get-childitem to work with foreach.

This is what I have so far and the error I'm getting:

CODE

```
$FilesList = Get-ChildItem -name -recurse -include *.mkv,*.mp4,*.srt,*.avi
$FilesList

foreach ($FL_Item in $FilesList)
    {
    $SeriesName = ($FL_Item.BaseName -split '\.s\d')[0].Replace('.', ' ')
    $SE_Info = $FL_Item.BaseName.Split('.')[-3] -split 'e'`

    $Season = $SE_Info[0] -replace 's', 'Season '
    #$Episode = 'Episode{0}' -f $SE_Info[1]

    $SeriesName
    $Season
    #$Episode

    $SeriesDirectory = Join-Path -Path "$SeriesName" -ChildPath "$Season"
    $SeriesDirectory

    #$MoverArchivo = move-item -path $FileName -destination e:\series\$SeriesDirectory
    #$MoverArchivo

    ''
    }
```

OUTPUT I'm getting

```
Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi
Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.spa.srt
Breaking.Bad.S04E01.Box.Cutter.720p.hdtv.x264-orenji.mkv
Breaking.Bad.S04E01.Box.Cutter.720p.hdtv.x264-orenji.spa.srt
Breaking.Bad.S05E15.720p.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.mkv
Breaking.Bad.S05E15.720p.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.spa.srt
Path Of Blood (2018) [WEBRip] [1080p] [YTS.AM]\Path.Of.Blood.2018.1080p.WEBRip.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4
They Shall Not Grow Old (2018) [BluRay] [1080p] [YTS.AM]\They.Shall.Not.Grow.Old.2018.1080p.BluRay.x264-[YTS.AM].mp4
```

ERROR

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At D:\shared\temp\test3.ps1:8 char:5
+     $SE_Info = $FL_Item.BaseName.Split('.')[-3] -split 'e'
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull

Cannot index into a null array.
At D:\shared\temp\test3.ps1:10 char:5
+     $Season = $SE_Info[0] -replace 's', 'Season '
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray


Join-Path : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Path' because it is an empty string.
At D:\shared\temp\test3.ps1:17 char:37
+     $SeriesDirectory = Join-Path -Path "$SeriesName" -ChildPath "$Sea ...
+                                        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Join-Path], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorEmptyStringNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Join
   PathCommand
```

Any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: I think the Digital Rights Management may be wrong :P

Comment: The last two filenames have a different format, so the split doesn't work for those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a RegEx with (named) capture groups to grep the Series,Season and Episode number.
See the RegEx working live on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/qZow9A/1)

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\20\SO_53875674.ps1
$DstBase = "E:\series"
Get-ChildItem -Include *.mkv,*.mp4,*.srt,*.avi -Recurse -File|
  Where-Object BaseName -match "^(?<Series>.*?)\.?S(?<Season>\d{1,2})\.?E(?<Episode>\d{2})"|
    ForEach-Object {
      $Destination = "{0}\{1}\Season {2:00}\" -f $DstBase,$Matches.Series.replace('.',' ').Trim(),[int]$Matches.Season
      if (!(Test-Path $Destination)){MD $Destination -Force | Out-Null}
      "Moving file [{0}] to [{1}]" -f $_.FullName,$Destination
      $_ | Move-Item -Destination $Destination -Force
    }
```

Sample tree (with above data) after running the script:

```
> tree /F
└───series
    └───Breaking Bad
        ├───Season 01
        │       Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.avi
        │       Breaking.Bad.S01E01.DVDRip.XviD-ORPHEUS.spa.srt
        │
        ├───Season 04
        │       Breaking.Bad.S04E01.Box.Cutter.720p.hdtv.x264-orenji.mkv
        │       Breaking.Bad.S04E01.Box.Cutter.720p.hdtv.x264-orenji.spa.srt
        │
        └───Season 05
                Breaking.Bad.S05E15.720p.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.mkv
                Breaking.Bad.S05E15.720p.HDTV.x264-EVOLVE.spa.srt
```

Comment: Hi, my answer below

Comment: @MarianoCandial While your **NON** answer got deleted meanwhile I can still read it.  I noticed the `Big Bang Theory` files have only one place for the season number which would exclude them in the Where-Object - I change that in the RegEx. Also files with a series name ending with a space cuased the error. The directory got created without that trailing space while it was still appended to the variable `$Destination`. Included a `.Trim()` to solve this. BTW If an answer solves your question you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Comment: Thank you, I'll check that. Sorry for not accepting your answer, this is my first time in stackoverflow.

Comment: Another change is needed if  you want to have **ALL** season numbers with two places, ATM you may get several dirs `Season 4`/`Season 04` if the files differ in that.

Comment: Yeah! I saw that, It should force always to re-write it as Season 04 as that's the way I have it organized. I'm investigating on how to show a progress bar of move-item or at least to show it´s result. Any ideas on that?

Comment: Btw the script worked like a charm! Thank you so much. I'll start trying to understand what it does piece by piece as I'm new to powershell scripting.

Comment: For learning Regular Expressions see https://www.regular-expressions.info/ and study the explanation in the inserted regex101.com link above in the answer.

Comment: One question, in regex101.com says S matches the character S literally (case sensitive) but it´s working both S and s. How so?

Comment: That's a powershell standard, to change that behaviour you need to use the `-cmatch` operator instead of `-match` read [Get-Help about_comparison_operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-5.1) or follow the link

Comment: Is there a way to see what is the script doing on screen? Like Moving file "bla bla bla"

Comment: I accepted it yesterday, I did it wrong? What did you change? it's an improvment or it does something new?

Comment: Yes, I saw the moving verbose and it´s awesome. Thank you so much

Answer (score 3):

You are using the `-name` parameter of `Get-ChildItem` in your first line:

```
$FilesList = Get-ChildItem -name -recurse -include *.mkv,*.mp4,*.srt,*.avi
```

which means it will return just the names of the files as strings.

Later, in your loop, you access each element using the `BaseName` property, which is a property of `FileInfo` objects, not strings. So, `$FL_Item.BaseName` returns an empty string and you get the errors as shown.

Just remove the `-name` and it should work (or at least you won't get those errors).